# unable to correctly read multivalue settings from appsettings.json in Asp.net Core 6

Tags: appsettings, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an Asp.net core 3.1 application i wanto to migrate to Asp.Net Core 6 .
I have some difficulties in correctly reading a multivalue section of appsettngs.json

Let's say my json file is the following and i need to read the "Settings" section that can have more than one child AND i do not know how many in advance:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

   "Settings": {

      "Set00": {
        "Property1": "value1",
        "Property2": "value2",
        "Property3": "value3",
      },

      "Set01": {
        "Property1": "value4",
        "Property2": "value5",
        "Property3": "value6",
      }

   },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

To do that i created this classes:

```
public class Settings
{
    List<SettingProperties> Settings {get; set;}
}

public class SettingProperties
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }  
    public string Property2 { get; set; }  
    public string Property3 { get; set; }  
}
```

Then in Program.cs i add

```
var mysettings = new Settings();
builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Settings)).Bind(mysettings);
```

Then in my controller i use DI to be able to reach the configuration

```
private readonly Settings _MysettingsM;
public ApplicationController(
                        IOptions<Settings> APPsettings,
        )
    {
        _MysettingsM = APPsettings.Value;
    }
```

but already on building the mysettings variable it contains only null 'Settings' elements.

Where am i wrong ?
P.S. the same if I change Settings class and explicity i define it as

```
public class Settings
{
    SettingProperties Set00 {get; set;}
    SettingProperties Set01 {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

Settings:

```
public class Settings
    {
        public SettingProperties Set00 { get; set; }
        public SettingProperties Set01 { get; set; }
    }
```

Register in Program:

```
builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks !I mean the 'key' of the solution is the instruction     builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));

Comment: Hi @NicolaAgostoni any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.